# Best apporach to filter data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 sets of columns in a Table:

- Provider Languages: Column1 - Column4
- Office Languages: Column5 - Column8

My task is if Provider Languages are less then 4, pick languages from Office Languages column set that are not present in Provider Languages.

Example:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4    Column5   Column6   Column7   Column8

English   Tamil               Swedish    English   German
```

In the example  above the result should be English,Tamil,Swedish,German

I need to do all of this in SQL, and I am having no idea as to how do I approach this with just SQL. Any help/idea with regards to this would be appreciated.

My approach has been to concatenate all the provider languages in a CSV format:

```
English, Tamil, Swedish (Done this)
```

Next, I check the count of the number of languages. Here the example would be 3 (done this).

Now I need to do a similar task for staff languages: English, German (done this)

But now comes the problem:

I have 2 strings:

1. English, Tamil, Swedish
2. English, German

I need to generate a final string having English, Tamil, Swedish, German. And this is the part I am not able to figure out. I thought my approach might be incorrect and that's why I wanted to know if someone had a better idea.

Sorry if some of you felt I didn't provide enough info.

Comment: What have you tried so far? No matter how simple your attempt was we're here to help you ;)

Comment: This post really doesn't show any research or effort on your part.  What have you researched, tried, and found to not provide you with your desired output?

Comment: You should probably expand on 'better'? In what way is the reply unsuitable? too much code?

Answer (score 2):

I would call this very tricky.  One approach is to unpivot the data, select the values that are not `NULL`, enumerate them, and then reaggregate to get four languages.

This is cumbersome.  It is possible to do using `join` and `group by` and some other logic.  An alternative uses `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, x.*
from t outer apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as value1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as value2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as value3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end) as value4
      from (select val, row_number() over (order by min(pos)) as seqnum
            from (values(1, value1), (2, value2), (3, value3) . . .) v(pos, val)
            where val is not null
            group by val
           ) x
     ) x;
```

Removing the duplicates is handled by the `group by` in the innermost query.  Each value only appears once in the result from the query -- even if present in multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the below code. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID int, Languages Varchar (8000))
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Languages Varchar (8000))

INSERT @Table
(ID,Languages)
VALUES
(1,'English, Tamil, Swedish'),
(2,'English, German')

-- Execution Part
INSERT INTO @temp
(Languages)
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Languages FROM  
    (SELECT ID,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Languages, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Languages FROM @Table A) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Languages.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT DISTINCT Languages = 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Languages
               FROM @temp b 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM @temp a
```